# Cashier or casher

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word `casher`? (I'm facing it from time to time in different online/electronic dictionaries).

If so, what is the difference between `casher` and `cashier`?

*UPD:* Is it a just a typo or slang/coined word? I don't see it in any serious dictionaries, but in [informal ones](http://www.yourdictionary.com/casher) or even [wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/casher).

*UPD2:* My question is rather connected to gambling terminology/slang. Is the person who deposits money on gambler's account and performs wins payout  called `cashier`, and `casher` is just a typo? Or is it a coined word for this kind of human activity?

Thanks.

Comment: The Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=casher%2Ccashier&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccasher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccashier%3B%2Cc0 shows a zero presence of 'casher' against 'cashier'.

Comment: It's a typo. Lots of typos are indexed by google that are just not things.

Comment: Since the original close reason was lack of included research, and since the poster has edited the question to add a couple of relevant data points of research, it seems to me that the close reason is no longer valid and we should reopen the question. Unless, of course, the close voters were just stringing the poster along with that request for research...

Answer (score 1):

According to dictionary.com, "casher" is not a word.

However, it has been assigned the informal meaning by various sources to mean "one who cashes a cheque" ([Source](http://www.yourdictionary.com/casher)).

"Cashier," on the other hand, is

> a person handling payments and receipts in a store, bank, or other business.

A "cashier" usually works behind a register at a bank (or a different place of business), while a "casher" would be the person handing a check to the "cashier" (according to the informal definition).

It is to be noted once more that "casher" is not technically a word, and should not be used in a formal setting.

Comment: s/in a formal setting//